# Hidden files are hidden (reproducible)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, linux, ubuntu

**Specification**:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Tor Browser Bundle: upgraded from 7.x to 8.0.3 (latest version)

**Issue (summary)**:
`FileChooser.show-hidden` is set to `false` after save and open dialog is canceled or saved/opened. (this "registry" key determines whether or not hidden files are shown in Nautilus, the default file manager for Ubuntu)

**Question**:
How do I prevent TBB from setting `org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser` to `false` after save and open dialog is canceled or saved/opened?

**Example**:

```
$ gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden
> true

  - open tor browser
  - use control+o or control+s

  - Close the dialog (using 'x' in the corner OR save to a file OR open a file)

$ gsettings get org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser show-hidden
> false
```